# How to log Facebook Webhooks with Watson Assistant? Used for Handover Protocol

Tags: facebook, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I wish to use the handover protocol for facebook messenger integration.

What I need is to get the recipient ID from the facebook messengers webhooks, which I have subscribed to: messages, messaging_postbacks, standby, messaging_handovers

I been trying to log out the webhooks, but I cannot find how to do so. I tried by logging

```
< ? context? >
< ? input ? > 
< ? output ? >
```

but none contain the recipient.

References:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol#overview

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/handover-protocol/pass-thread-control

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language

Comment: Are you using the FB integration offered by WA or something different?

Comment: I am using FB integration directly from WA.

Comment: @data_henrik I been reading that it might not be possible if I am using the integration offered by WA. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Not much. It seems like the itegration is an app on its own. Hence, there is no need to pass through any FB info. I have used Botkit with WA before and had control over the FB data.

Comment: I see, well, going to keep searching how to make the handover protocol with facebook. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported in the direct facebook integration. As stated above its an app that we host internally so is not ultimately flexible or configurable for everything facebook supports. If you want more power check out the botkit middleware which is an open source application framework that can get your Assistant connected to facebook, but is more open so you can configure for the agent protocol as needed
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this should be a feature integrated, since handover protocol is a very common use case. I will check botkit and host an app to test.